# Codeigniter ou PHP Queue (fila)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Estou fazendo um envio massivo de arquivos para um servidor de fotos.

Ocorre que até enviar todas as fotos, o usuário acaba esperando um tempão. Aí me deram a dica de pesquisar sobre fila de espera ou queue.  Desta forma, o usuário poderia deixar a página de uploads e fazer outras coisas no sistema, enquanto por trás o PHP faria o envio.

No Codeigniter, não encontrei nada a respeito. Alguém sabe como fazer via PHP ou Codeigniter uma fila de espera de tarefas?

Comment: Eu sei trabalhar esse _upload_ sem incomodar o usuário nem dar _refresh_ na página. Mas se vc quer trocar de página enquanto faz o _upload_ (é o que parece), então eu acho que eu e você teremos que pesquisar mais. O problema é que, mesmo em requisições assíncronas, vc vai precisar do `JavaScript` e do _form_ carregado na memória (_browser_), e mudar de página não me parece ser uma boa ideia pq o negócio recarrega todo. Já vi coisas como _server side upload in php_, e creio ser possível, por causa do `CGI`, mas nunca me aventurei. Como disse, depende de (muita) pesquisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal no **Laravel** existe uma função cron que fica trabalhando no backstage, como se fosse o cronjob do linux.

Ocorre que não encontrei isto no **CodeIgniter**, o que fiz foi bem simples:

1- Criei uma tabela de cronjobs;
2- Ao upar as fotos para o sistema, o mesmo salva no cronjobs uma tarefa que é lançar para o outro servidor aos poucos;
3- Setei um cronjob que bate de tempos em tempos neste script, que analisa os cronjobs pendentes e faz o envio.

O negócio ficou tão bacana que estou usando para diversas outras funções, na qual o usuário não precisa aguardar (exemplo disparo de e-mails simples através do sistema, geração de relatórios mais pesados, etc).